# Hystrix With ExecutorService in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, executorservice, hystrix

I have a new service in Spring Boot. To Serve one request the service has to go to collect data from multiple sources with Executor Service in place. How do I use Hystrix in between this service and downstream service.

Link for the [service image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehkvL.jpg)

Lets say I have a SERVICE A that needs to call SERVICE B twice and the result from SERVICE B is needed to call SERVICE C 200 times, before it can response back. I have a Executor Service to Call services in parallel.

I have tried @HystrixCommand with SEMAPHORE Configuration for all service calls in between SERVICE A, SERVICE B and SERVICE C.

By time I the thread gets scheduled for SERVICE C, Hystrix kicks off and some of the 200 calls to SERVICE C from SERVICE A gets tripped.

Response time expected by SERVICE A : 1 sec
Response time of SERVICE B: 300 ms
Response time of SERVICE C: 40-100 ms

AWS Beanstalk Machine Used has 8 core CPU.

I have also used a redis Cache to cache the responses of SERVICE C. But SERVICE B call cannot be cached, it has dynamic result.

Executor Service Config:

```
    @Bean
    public Executor asyncGCPExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(30);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("async-");
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(10);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

Hystrix Config:

```
hystrix.command.default.fallback.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests=100
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy=SEMAPHORE
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=600
```

Tries a lot with different number of thread configs and timeout but it did not help.
Please guide me with the correct hystrix config.

Please let me know if the situation is unclear.

Some Code:

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
class CollectorController {

private final CollectorService collectorService;

public CollectorController(final CollectorService collectorService) {
    this.collectorService = collectorService;
}

@GetMapping(value = "/collections")
public ResponseEntity<List<String>>  getResponseForCollection(@ModelAttribute final Request request) {
    final List<String> response;
    try {
        response = this.collectorService.getCollections(request);
    } catch (final ExecutionException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);

}

}

@Data
class Request {
    private String username;
    private String cid;
}

@Service
class CollectorService {

private final ServiceA serviceA;
private final ServiceB serviceB;

private final ArrangementService arrangementService;

CollectorService(final ServiceA serviceA, final ServiceB serviceB,
                 final ArrangementService arrangementService) {
    this.serviceA = serviceA;
    this.serviceB = serviceB;
    this.arrangementService = arrangementService;
}

public List<String> getCollections(final Request request) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    final CompletableFuture<List<String>> collectionByUsernameAndCid = serviceA.getCollectionByUsernameAndCid(request);
    final List<CompletableFuture<String>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
    collectionByUsernameAndCid.get().forEach(source -> {
        final CompletableFuture<String> detailsBySource = serviceB.getDetailsBySource(source);
        completableFutures.add(detailsBySource);

    });
    final int size = completableFutures.size();
    CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[size])).join();
    return arrangementService.arrangeAll(completableFutures);
}

}

@Service
class ArrangementService {

public List<String> arrangeAll(final List<CompletableFuture<String>> completableFutureList) {

    return completableFutureList.stream().map(completableFuture -> {
        try {
            return completableFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

}

@Service
class ServiceA {

private final ServiceACollector serviceACollector;

ServiceA(final ServiceACollector serviceACollector) {
    this.serviceACollector = serviceACollector;
}

@Async
public CompletableFuture<List<String>> getCollectionByUsernameAndCid(final Request request) {
    final List<String> responseFromServiceA = serviceACollector.getResponseFromServiceA(request.getUsername(), request.getCid());
    if (null == responseFromServiceA || responseFromServiceA.isEmpty()) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
    }
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(responseFromServiceA);
}

}

@Service
class ServiceB {

private final ServiceBCollector serviceBCollector;

ServiceB(final ServiceBCollector serviceBCollector) {
    this.serviceBCollector = serviceBCollector;
}

@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> getDetailsBySource(final String source) {
    final String responseFromServiceB = serviceBCollector.getResponseFromServiceB(source);
    if (null == responseFromServiceB || responseFromServiceB.isEmpty()) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(responseFromServiceB);
}

}

@Service
class ServiceACollector {

private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

ServiceACollector(final RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}

/**
 * The CacheManager does not allow null values.
 * So if hystrix fallback method returns null then its not cached.
 *
 * @param username
 * @param cid
 * @return 200 list of String
 */
@Cacheable(key = "{#username, #cid}", cacheManager = "oneHourCacheManager", value = "ServiceACollector")
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "defaultResponseFromServiceA")
public List<String> getResponseFromServiceA(final String username, final String cid) {
    final ResponseEntity<List<String>> responseEntity = this.restTemplate.exchange(
            "http://my-rest-url.org/rest/account/{username}/{cid}", HttpMethod.GET,
            null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {
            }, username, cid);
    return responseEntity.getBody();
}

public List<String> defaultResponseFromServiceA(final String username, final String cid) {
    return null;
}

}

@Service
class ServiceBCollector {

public final RestTemplate restTemplate;


ServiceBCollector(final RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}

/**
 * The CacheManager does not allow null values.
 * So if hystrix fallback method returns null then its not cached.
 *
 *
 * @param source
 * @return
 */
@Cacheable(key = "{#source}", cacheManager = "oneHourCacheManager", value = "ServiceBCollector")
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "defaultResponseFromServiceB")
public String getResponseFromServiceB(final String source) {
    final ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = this.restTemplate.exchange(
            "http://my-rest-url.org/rest/details/{source}", HttpMethod.GET,
            null, String.class, source);
    return responseEntity.getBody();
}

public String defaultResponseFromServiceB(final String username, final String cid) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Please show your actual use of Hystrix. Without it will be difficult to reason about the question. The example executor doesn't help at all in this case.

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks for asking. Putting down some code.

``

Comment: @spencergibb Hystrix is used at each thread that calls external service. Its just the calling service is in Executor Service. And that why I have used SEMAPHORE.